# Parse.com Android Push Notifications With Url

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, push

I am trying to integrate parse into my app with push notifications and have the notification display  custom text and open the device's browser when I send a url to it.

The parse integration is fine(Thats the easy part) but where I am stuck is what to code for the integration for handling the json code sent by the parse interface and have the app translate it into the action I need done.

I know I will have to update the manifest file and the main activity class to accomplish this but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Add Manifest to

```
<receiver android:name="com.sample.app.android.recevier.PushNotificationRecevier" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.sample.app.android.SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create One receiver  Class

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class PushNotificationRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver{
    String SimpleNotification="com.sample.app.android.SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(SimpleNotification)){

            // Your Stuff 
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok got that, but not sure what to put in the "Your Stuff" area.  I know it has to decode the json query(Which I will have toy research how to construct as I am still new to java and json).  But also getting errors about: Broadcast Receiver, Context and Intent cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: u can use JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
form get json Object then u can parse ur own way.

Comment: Ok got that validated finally with a lot of checks from eclipse.  Nw for the JSON code.  I want to be able to send text and a url for the push to open in browser.  In your code I only see appID, packageName and versionCode.  I can pass these but what should I pass to send custom title, text and url.  Something Like This:  { “title”: “You Have a New Message”, “alert": “Here is some text”, “url”: “http://someurl.com” }

Comment: Please check my answer if it useful

Comment: Ok thanks for the update :)  Ok So it looks like it will accept and parse out the JSON data now, but what constructor needs to build to actually build the notification so everything gets sent correctly?

Under Your Stuff I edited it to this:

String title=jsonObject.getString("title");
String alert=jsonObject.optString("alert");
String url=jsonObject.optString("url");

Comment: @SelvaYakshis what if I want to unsubscribe?

Comment: @PsyDuck i didn't get u can u explain what u going to do exactly?

Comment: I am able to subscribe to a channel but I'm not able to unsubscribe. How can we do that? I'm using : `ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("channel_name");`